# React radio requires two clicks to trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
const Input = ({
    onChange,
    inputVal,
    currentVal,
    id,
}) => {
    const handleOnChange = e => {
        onChange(e);
    }

    return (
        <input 
            onChange={handleOnChange} 
            value={inputVal} 
            id={id} 
            type="radio" 
            checked={inputVal === currentVal} 
        />
    );
};
```

which I use like so:

```
const RampUp = ({            
    age, 
    columns, 
    ongoingMonthlyPayment,
    setYearlyContr,
    yearlyContr
}) => {

const [radioVal, setRadioVal] = useState("5");

const handleYearsSelection = val => { 
    setYearlyContr(parseInt(val));
    setRadioVal(val);
}
...
<Control flexGrow="2">
    <span>yearly</span>
    <span>monthly</span>
</Control>
<Control justifyContent="space-evenly" flexGrow="3">
    <div>
        <label htmlfor="a">5</label>
        <Input onChange={handleYearsSelection} inputVal="5" id="a" currentVal={radioVal} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlfor="b">10</label>
        <Input onChange={handleYearsSelection} inputVal="10" id="b" currentVal={radioVal} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlfor="c">15</label>
        <Input onChange={handleYearsSelection} inputVal="15" id="c" currentVal={radioVal} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label htmlfor="d">Max</label>
        <Input onChange={handleYearsSelection} inputVal={maxYears} id="d" currentVal={radioVal} />
    </div>
</Control>

...
```

for some reasons the first time is rendered I need to click twice to update the prop

> currentVal

even if I click on:

```
<Input onChange={handleYearsSelection} inputVal="10" id="b" currentVal={radioVal} />
```

for the first time the value of 'currentVal' is still 5 (default). It takes a second click to give me 10 in this case.

Comment: Can you add the `handleYearsSelection` function ?

Comment: The variable passed to `handleYearsSelection` is a change event not the value of the clicked `<input/>`.

Comment: Try: `onChange(e.target.value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the following one component up:

```
const [radioVal, setRadioVal] = useState("5");
```